# Docker: get/print ID of running container

Tags: bash, docker

The goal is to run script `setup-debian-server.sh` from host inside a container and commit an image if there were no errors.

This thing feeds the script lines as arguments to `bash` and appends to them `hostname` to print the ID of the container.

It passes the parameters to the script: `--script-par1=abc`.

```
(
    did="$(
        docker run ubuntu:15.04 /bin/bash -c "$(<./setup-debian-server.sh); echo; hostname;" -- --script-par1=abc |
        tail -n1;
        exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
    )" && docker commit "$did" my/base
)
```

The problem is that the `setup-debian-server.sh` stdout is lost. And it's overall ugly.

I've played with some `exec {FD}>&1` commands but that doesn't flush stdout reliably (I expect always 3 lines of output but it's sometimes 2):

```
(exec {FD}>&1 && /bin/bash -c "hostname; echo 123;" | tee /dev/fd/$FD | head -n1)
```

How to do that simple task?